# Partial colouring of text in an excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large set of data in excel. I wish to colour only text "ADC" out of entire text in a cell, and do same dynamically in entire data range. Please help me if there is a way.

Comment: Can you show a sample data set, and what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small demo that you can adapt to your needs.  It will examine the texts in cells **A1** through **A10** and color all *ADC*s red.  Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub ADC()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, L As Long, i As Long
    
    For Each r In Range("A1:A10")
        s = r.Text
        L = Len(s)
        If L > 2 Then
            For i = 1 To L - 2
                If Mid(s, i, 1) = "A" And Mid(s, i + 1, 1) = "D" And Mid(s, i + 2, 1) = "C" Then
                    r.Characters(i, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

the result:

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. it will not work on formula cells

Answer (score 0):

You can't partial color/highlight cells in Excel. To workaround this, insert a shape in the cell and change the fill color. Or if you want to add some other text, erase the previous text, insert a textbox then.